# Making a SOAP Call with WS-Addressing using PowerShell New-WebServiceProxy

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a SOAP call to a web service using PowerShell's New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet. The web services uses SOAP 1.2 and requires WS-addressing. Is there a way to provide the XML request with the New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet?

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter username";
$securePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString;
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securePassword);

$uri = "https://service.svc?wsdl"

$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Credential $credential

$service.method()
```

That code returns "The underlying connection was closed". Using SOAPUI with WS-Addressing enabled it will correctly return a result.

Comment: Please show us your code, and tell us what you have tried, what went wrong, what did you expect to happen, what happened instead, etc. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added my PS code with the error message.

Comment: `New-WebServiceProxy` has no knobs or switches, it either works or it doesn't. Under the hood it uses the classes in `System.Web.Services` to generate the proxy, meaning that you'd likely also run into trouble with the native .NET Framework tools, but there's more leeway there (or at least more error feedback). You can try using `wsdl` or `svcutil` to generate proxy classes, but this requires that you know your way around .NET development.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, that was kind of what I was assuming, but wanted to make sure there was no way to add a custom SOAP XML header/body to try do it easily.